# PostgreSQL compare a timestamp with timezone with a timestamp

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

How do you compare a timestamp with a timezone with a timestamp in postgresql?
I am trying to cast one of the 2 to the type of the other but it does not work for me. Eg.

Having

```
TS1: 2019-01-07 21:43:00
```

and

```
TS2: 2019-01-07 20:43:37+01
```

I need to compare them and check if they are the same not including the seconds. So I have tried with:

```
select attimestamp, attimestamp_tz, attimestam=attimestamp_tz::timestamp from attendance where atid=1070
```

but this will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

> ```sql
> create table test (ts1 timestamp without time zone, ts2 timestamp with time zone)
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```sql
> insert into test (ts1, ts2) 
> VALUES ('2019-01-07 21:43:00', '2019-01-07 20:43:37+01'), 
>        ('2019-01-07 21:43:00', '2019-01-07 20:43:37-01')
> ```
>
> ```
> 2 rows affected
> ```

> ```sql
> select *, 
>        to_char(ts1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') str_ts1, 
>        to_char(ts2, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') str_ts2, 
>        to_char(ts1, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') = to_char(ts2, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI') compare 
> from test
> ```
>
> ```
> ts1                 | ts2                    | str_ts1      | str_ts2      | compare
> :------------------ | :--------------------- | :----------- | :----------- | :------
> 2019-01-07 21:43:00 | 2019-01-07 19:43:37+00 | 201901072143 | 201901071943 | f      
> 2019-01-07 21:43:00 | 2019-01-07 21:43:37+00 | 201901072143 | 201901072143 | t
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5c60d53db1ca34fdf84b69facb0db64c)*